# MSSQL 2012 64 bit ANSI_PADDING error inconsistent results across connections

Tags: sql-server, connection

I have two connections to the same db on the same server, with the same user, 
as open windows in Sequel Server Management studio.

On the first I run:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
 SET ANSI_PADDING ON
 SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
 SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
 SET ARITHABORT OFF
 SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 DELETE from GPSData where GPSDateTime BETWEEN '2014-06-09' AND    '2014-06-11'
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
```

and the error is:

Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
DELETE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

When I run the same transaction on the other connection, the error is:

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_GPSUnit_GPSData". The conflict occurred in database "PLATO_PEP", table "dbo.GPSUnit", column 'GPSDataID'.
The statement has been terminated.

The second error I expect to see.  How can the first connection give an ANSI_PADDING... error, when the same settings work on the second connection?

Comment: What does `SELECT @@OPTIONS` show you if you run it instead of your `DELETE`?

Comment: it returns 5432

Comment: Well, if it returns the same on both, then your options are definitely identical, so that eliminates that. My only *guess* would be that for some reason the queries generate different plans to do the same job (show us the query plans for both!), and that in one version the foreign key constraint problem gets detected before the problem created by the options. That is, each query stops at the first error it encounters while actually processing the data, and one is processing the data in a different order from the other. (The optimiser doesn't guarantee to use the same plan for the same query.)